# Binding Object of an object to Form

Tags: java, forms, playframework-2.3, custom-formatting

I have following models:

```
public class Color {
    public String name;
    public Long id;
    public String rgb;
//setters, getters
}

public class Product {

  private static List<Product> products;

  static {
    products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    products.add(new Product("1111111111111", "Paperclips 1",
        "Paperclips description 1", new Color(1L,"yellow","ff4400")));
    products.add(new Product("2222222222222", "Paperclips 2",
        "Paperclips description ",new Color(2L,"red","ff1100")));
    products.add(new Product("3333333333333", "Paperclips 3",
        "Paperclips description 3",new Color(3L,"brown","ff8800")));
    products.add(new Product("4444444444444", "Paperclips 4",
        "Paperclips description 4",new Color(4L,"blue","ff4400")));
    products.add(new Product("5555555555555", "Paperclips 5",
        "Paperclips description 5",new Color(5L,"black","ff4400")));
  }

  @Constraints.Required
  public String ean;
  @Constraints.Required
  public String name;
  public String description;
  public Color color;

  public Product() {
  }

  public Product(String ean, String name, String description, Color color) {
    this.ean = ean;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.color = color;
  }
//other methods required by controller
}
```

And a view which shows a product form:

```
@(productForm: Form[Product])
@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@main("Product form") {
  <h1>Product form</h1>
  @helper.form(action = routes.Products.save()) {
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Product (@productForm("name").valueOr("New"))</legend>
      @helper.inputText(productForm("ean"), '_label -> "EAN")
      @helper.inputText(productForm("name"),'_label -> "Name")
      @helper.textarea(productForm("description"), '_label -> "Description")
      @helper.inputText(@productForm("color.id"),'_label -> " @productForm('color.name') : @productForm('color.rgb')")
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
     <a class="btn" href="@routes.Products.index()">Cancel</a>
  }
}
```

My question concerns the line:

```
@helper.inputText(@productForm("color.id"),'_label -> " @productForm('color.name') : @productForm('color.rgb')")
```

I know it is not correct, but I need something like this, i.e. to access object of an object in a form, and it also should be both bindable and unbindable as any field of Form[Product]. Is it possible? If not, how usually people go about such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the contents of fields using `value`, for example

```
productForm("color.name").value.getOrElse("unknown")
```

If it gets a bit unwieldy, or you want to reuse it, you can define it as a template variable with `defining`:

```
@defining( productForm("color.name").value.getOrElse("unknown")+" : "+productForm("color.rgb").value.getOrElse("-") ) { colorLabel =>
   @helper.inputText(@productForm("color.id"), '_label -> colorLabel)
```